# multiple inserts node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, json

i am new in node.js ,
I have in my sql database 2 tables , a table called club and a table called players , they are connected by one to many relation , so i created a post query in Flutter , and from my query i want to send the name of the club , the price of the club to insert them on the first table team , and in the same query send the list of selected players of the team and do a loop for to insert them in the second table players and insert the id of the club for every player, but i found my self do not know what should i right in Flutter or Node.js , i am trying to find the right syntax for what i have tried, after execution i had an error in node.js that says

`unexpected end of json input because probably of players(that is a table and not a field in table club)`

here what i have tried:

```
create:(data,callback)=>{
    pool.query(
      insert into club(userid,name,price) values(?,?,?),

      [
        data.userid,
        data.name,
        data.price,

      ],
      (error,results,fields)=>{
        if(error){
          callback(error);
        }
        return callback(null,results);
      }
    );
    for(item in data.players){
    pool.query(

      `insert into players(id,firstname,lastname,position,price,appearences,goals,
        assists,cleansheets,redcards,yellowcards,image,clubid) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)`,

      [
        data.players.id,
        data.players.firstname,
        data.players.lastname,
        data.players.position,
        data.players.price,
        data.players.appearences,
        data.players.goals,
        data.players.assists,
        data.players.cleansheets,
        data.players.redcards,
        data.players.yellowcards,
        data.players.image,
        data.players.clubid,
        

      ],
      (error,results,fields)=>{
        if(error){
          callback(error);
        }
        return callback(null,results);
      }
    );
  }
  },
```

here how my database looks like:

table club: id userid

table players: id firstname lastname position price appearences goals assists cleansheets redcards yellowcards image clubid

clubid is a foreign key of the table club
i know that it should be the last inserted id but i do not know how to do the right syntax

Any help will be so appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems here.

First, the unique `clubid` you'll use for your second INSERT is, I guess, generated by MySQL's autoincrement feature when you do your first INSERT. You can get it in the callback from your query in `result.insertId`. Then pass it to the second query.

Second, you're not handling the asynchronous nature of MySQL queries correctly here. You cannot perform your second INSERT until you know the first one has finished.  So, you must do your second INSERT from inside the callback of the first query.

Or better yet use the [mysql2 package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) and `async` / `await`. Something like this (NOT debugged).

```js
create: async (data,callback) => {                               /* async!   */
    const myPool = pool.promise()                                /* promise! */
    const {results, fields} = await myPool.query(                /* await!   */
            'insert into club(userid,name,price) values(?,?,?)',
            [ data.userid, data.name, data.price] )
    const clubid = results.insertId
    for(item in data.players) {
        const {results, fields} = await myPool.query(            /* await!   */
           `insert into players
               (id, firstname, lastname, position, 
                price, appearences, goals, assists, 
                 cleansheets, redcards, yellowcards, 
                 image, clubid)
              values(?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`,
            [   /* NOTE use   item.whatever   not   data.players.whatever,
                 * because data.players is an array of objects  */
                item.id, item.firstname, item.lastname, item.position, 
                item.price, item.appearences, item.goals, item.assists,
                item.cleansheets, item.redcards, item.yellowcards,
                item.image,
                clubid ]   /* NOTE not item.clubid ! */
               )
       } /* end for (item in data.players) */
    }
}
```

**Pro tip:** It's worth every second of the time it takes you to figure out `async` / `await` and the related `Promises` APIs. If you don't you get into so-called "callback hell" . It has a sign on it saying ["abandon every hope, ye who enter here."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inferno_(Dante)#Vestibule_of_Hell)

Comment: will this function recognize data.players?

Comment: no field in any table called players , players is the chid table

Comment: in case yes can you show me how should be the body in postman?

Comment: Use a debugger. Step through the code line by line.